# Good practice to call high amount of request to a limited requests per second API

Tags: python, api, rest, google-tag-manager, quota

I'm currently trying to use a one of Google API Service (GTM) and I'm limited to 1 request per second.

Some action required a lot of calls and even batched, it takes time and take all the quota per second. The problem is that multiple user can run an action simultaneously and usually the first ran take all the quota putting the other ones in error (the execution time is not an issue here).

Pseudo-code exemple of one of the action:

```
funct create_asset:
   create_tags() # Creation of around 200 tags
   create_variables() # Creation of around 200 variables
   create_folders() # Creation of around 50 folders
   create_triggers() # Creation of around 50 triggers
```

I was thinking of creating a queue for the request like that the call for the action of each user are mixed together and run one by one (for exemple if we take the pseudo-code above, if two users use the action that calls create_asset(), the queue could looks something like `[user1-create_tags(), user2-create_tags(), user1-create_variables(), user2-create_variables(), user1-create_folders(), user1-create_triggers(), user2-create_folders(), user2-create_triggers()]`).

But I'd like to know the good practice for that or if there's a better way to handle that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I probably wouldn't interleave the calls like that unless there's good reason. If anything, it means that each call will take `~n*2` time to complete, vs one of `n` and the other `n*2`. A consumer queue doesn't sound like a bad idea. There's plenty of tech like RabbitMQ and Kafka that can allow you to make request queues or topics where you can have a limited set of workers pulling from them.

Comment: If you're playing in the cloud world with kubernetes, [Argo workflows](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/) are also great technology for managing ingestion workflows like this. They offer configurations like max parallel jobs and other fun toggles